# Compiling 32-bit code with 64-bit MinGW GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, 32-bit

I am trying to build a C++ project. In 64bits everything goes well, but I need in 32bits. GCC is complaining... output :

```
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW_std-Windows/driver.o.d"
g++ -m32   -c -g -s -std=c++14  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW_std-Windows/driver.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW_std-Windows/driver.o driver.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW_std-Windows
g++ -m32    -o dist/Debug/MinGW_std-Windows/libdriver17.dll build/Debug/MinGW_std-Windows/driver.o  -shared
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../..\libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW_std-Windows/libdriver17.dll] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/d/documents/test/driver17'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/documents/test/driver17'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 3s)
```

IDE : Apache Netbeans IDE 11.2

GCC : 11.2.0

Any idea to fix that please ?
Is there a way to target by default a 32bits architecture in GCC settings ?

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

Comment: @dratenik I don't find any MinGW32 bits... Do you know why ? Or am I just a noob ?

Comment: The lesson of the link is that you want a `multilib` build and the keyword should also be visible in `gcc -v`. Some slightly older versions https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Multilib%20Toolchains%28Targetting%20Win32%20and%20Win64%29/

Comment: Your compiler is willing to compile 32-bit code, but you are missing the 32-bit libraries for it.

Comment: I don't even need to compile in 64bits because my target is anyway a 32bits computer. In the link you shared, are the sources safe ?

Comment: The link is reachable from the official mingw site. But if you suspect that I may have posted a malicious link, there is little point in asking me, is there...

Comment: Sorry if I offended you, but I was just asking. It confuses me why install links aren't available directly in official mingw site...

Comment: No offense here, I'm rather amused. The problem of https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/ is possibly the opposite one - too many links...

Comment: my `g++ -v` outputs `Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32`. Doesn't it mean 32bits architectures ? Btw thank's for you answers.

Comment: @dratenik anyway I got it, thank you mate